# How to install a drupal distribution using Drush quickstart command?

Tags: drush

What is the command for drush qc to install a drupal distribution? I'm trying to install this one: https://drupal.org/project/onepagecv

Answer (score 1):

The drush command is

```
drush site-install <profile>
```

as noted here in the [quickstart documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/install/developers), you can use this to install a full drupal site using a specific profile from a single command, ex:

```
drush site-install onepagecv --db-url=mysql://[db_user]:[db_pass]@localhost/[db_name] --site-name=Example
```

This assumes you already have Drupal core downloaded and this profile in your profiles folder.